# Using DevExtreme in an Angular App. How to write unit test case in Jasmine/Karma

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, devextreme

I have an Angular controller in which I have defined my DevExtreme JavaScript object through which I load a grid on the UI. I am unable to write unit test cases for the piece of code that is being used by DevExtreme.

How can I mock the DevExtreme dependency to test out Angular controllers. Are any examples available for this?

Comment: Why do you need to mock DevExtreme controls?

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten thank you for your response.

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten how do i unit test the dev extreme code in my controller file. angularjs

Comment: You don't need to test DevExtreme code. Only yours. Give me a sample of what code you have and how you wish to test it.

Comment: This question is rather brief and was unclear to readers at the time. I suggest that it is put on hold for now.